# Replacing values and getting "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace 0s and 1s with 'No' and 'Yes'.

I know there'll be a cleaner way of writing but main problem is I cant understand why I get the warning and code doesnt work.

```
age_group_clean['has_health_problem'].replace(['0'],'No', inplace=True)
age_group_clean['has_health_problem'].replace(['1'],'Yes', inplace=True)

/Users/kerrimac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6746: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

Comment: is `age_group_clean` a part of a bigger dataframe? maybe doing `age_group_clean = age_group_clean.copy()` before any modification helps.

Comment: Might be better to use `np.where()`, or `map()` the values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Trenton McKinney, Many thanks, that web page didn't solve problem but it gave me better understanding

Comment: np.where(), or map() just gave same result :-)

Comment: It was part of a bigger dataframe.  I actually just went back and made the change in the data frame ... Didn't try .copy() but will give it a go next time I face .  Thanks for advice.